# Correctly distributing a Java Desktop Application

Tags: java, desktop-application, distribution

I would like to distribute a program I'm halfway done writing but I'm having trouble figuring a few things out...

1. needs to check for latest JRE and check for updates/patches to my app (jnlp?)
2. the program will have one or two built in encryptions so I need to somehow wrap it in an .exe shell maybe..? (NSIS?)  How do I lock down my code?
3. Upon install I need to create a directory where my app can read and write from    automatically so I can save settings and log in info to the client's computer, and then be able to automatically reference it from then forward.

I feel like the jump to being able to do a few things with Java to distributing an app with these prerequisites is a large one, I'd appreciate any advice or wisdom you can share.

Comment: Isn't Java WebStart supposed to help with most of these questions?

Comment: Please please correct me if I'm wrong, but JNLP doesn't seem to provide me with any way to change the .jnlp icon from a coffee mug.  I would love to use JNLP alongside some other program that would give my desktop app a more professional feel, like install to Program files, custom icon for an .exe.  If I could use JNLP along side some other program that could accomplish these I would be set... advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the executable with a third-party tool like [exe4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html). It will check for compatible versions of Java, and supports a bundled JRE. An overview of signing and verifying jar files is [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html). You may also choose to [obfuscate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code) your code to protect it from prying eyes.

To store user settings in files with Java SE, you can get the user's home directory via the system property "user.home". Alternatively, you can store user settings with the Java Preferences API; on Windows, this stores in the registry.

I'm guessing you're using Swing. But if you happen to be using the Eclipse rich-client platform:

- RCP has its own preferences API for storing user settings.
- RCP's provisioning system p2 supports configuration management and updates of components within an application.

Comment: So forgive my ignorance... what would be the order in which I do these things?  So I finish the app through Eclipse RCP, obfuscate it, then wrap it with exe4j?  How would you go about it?

Comment: If you're building an application atop SWT/JFace/RCP rather than Swing, you can create and run a product build in the Eclipse IDE, which results in an executable, making something like exe4j unnecessary. Otherwise, you could obfuscate your Java code internals, then create an executable with exe4j or the like.